# Maps Api load from mysql with type marker

Tags: mysql, api, maps, google-maps-markers

**I have some questions and need help with Google Maps Api.**

1. When you hover on the list does not highlight the marker on the map.

2. When you click in the list does not show the marker on the map.

3. How to load markers from a MYSQL database, only the selected type of marker, eg. A bar or restaurant? eg. http: //www....../bar (and loads only the markers bar), .... / restaurant / (and loads only the markers restaurant)

Now loads me all the markers from the database.

Demo: [enter link description here](http://tomsia.pl/24nadobe/index11.php)

**phpsqlajax_genxml.php**

```
<markers>
<marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Buddha Thai & Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar"/>
<marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

**Index.php**

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
 var gmarkers = []; 
    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'a.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'b.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
    var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow,
   draggable: true
          });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    var marker_num = gmarkers.length-1;
    document.getElementById('pasekBoczny').innerHTML+='<li><a href="javascript:myclick(' + marker_num + ')">'+name+'</a></li>';
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
 
        }
      });
    }

 function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], "click");
}
 
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  
  
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
<link href="select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
<div id="logo">
<img src="logo-24nadobe.png" alt="Logo 24nadobe.pl">
</div>
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
<select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 50%" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<optgroup label="Urzędy i Instytucje">
<option></option>
<option value="http://www.google.pl">Starostwa Powiatowe</option>
<option value="#">Urząd Miasta/Gminy</option>
<option value="#">Państwowa Inspekcja Pracy</option>
<option value="#">Urząd Pracy</option>
<option value="#">Zakład Ubezpieczeń Społecznych</option>
<option value="#">Inspekcja Sanitarna</option>
<option value="#">Policja Komendy i Komisariaty</option>
<option value="#">Straż Pożarna</option>
<option value="#">Urząd Skarbowy</option>
<option value="#">Sąd i Prokuratura</option>
<optgroup label="Sklepy">
<option value="#">Markety</option>
<option value="#">Komputerowe</option>
<option value="#">Rowerowe</option>
<option value="#">Spożywcze</option>
<option value="#">Monopolowe</option>
<option value="#">24H</option>
<option value="#">Zoologiczny</option>
<option value="#">Mięsny</option>
<option value="#">Budownictwo</option>
<option value="#">Biżuteria</option>
<option value="#">Odzież</option>
<optgroup label="Finansowe">
<option value="#">Banki</option>
<option value="#">Bankomaty</option>
<option value="#">Kantory</option>
<option value="#">Ubezpieczenia</option>
<optgroup label="Zdrowie i Uroda">
<option value="#">Salony Fryzjerskie</option>
<option value="#">Solaria i kosmetyczki</option>
<option value="#">Dentyści</option>
<option value="#">Szpitale</option>
<option value="#">Przychodnie</option>
<option value="#">Lekarze</option>
<option value="#">Okuliści</option>
<optgroup label="Przesyłki">
<option value="#">Paczkomaty</option>
<option value="#">Kurierzy</option>
<optgroup label="Komunikacja">
<option value="#">Dworce PKS</option>
<option value="#">Dworce PKP</option>
<option value="#">Busy</option>
<option value="#">Parkingi</option>
<optgroup label="Gastronomia">
<option value="#">Bary/Puby</option>
<option value="#">Cukiernie i Piekarnie</option>
<option value="#">Pizzerie</option>
<option value="#">Kebaby</option>
<option value="#">McDonalds</option>
<option value="#">Restauracje</option>
<option value="#">Kawiarnie</option>
<optgroup label="Usługi">
<option value="#">Krawiectwo</option>
<option value="#">Kwiaciarnia</option>
<option value="#">Zakład fotograficzny</option>
<option value="#">Telefony</option>
<option value="#">Drukarnie</option>
<option value="#">Dla dzieci</option>
<option value="#">Wypożyczalnie</option>
<optgroup label="Motoryzacja">
<option value="#">Autokomisy</option>
<option value="#">Części samochodowe</option>
<option value="#">Elektromechanika </option>
<option value="#">Myjnie</option>
<option value="#">Salony samochodowe</option>
<option value="#">Stacje paliw</option>
<option value="#">Warsztaty samochodowe</option>
<option value="#">Warsztaty lakiernicze</option>
<option value="#">Wulkanizacja</option>
<optgroup label="Nauka i Edukacja">
<option value="#">Szkoły Wyższe</option>
<option value="#">Szkoły językowe</option>
<option value="#">Księgarnie</option>
<option value="#">Biblioteki</option>
<optgroup label="Inne">
<option value="#">Kościoły</option>
<option value="#">Cmentarze</option>
<option value="#">Kapliczki</option>
<option value="#">Weterynarze</option>
<option value="#">Prasa</option>
<option value="#">Ślub i wesele</option>
<optgroup label="Rozrywka i Kultura">
<option value="#">Kina</option>
<option value="#">Centra kultury</option>
<option value="#">Dyskoteki</option>
<option value="#">Lotto</option>
<option value="#">Muzea</option>
<optgroup label="Turystyka">
<option value="#">Biura podróży</option>
<option value="#">Hotele i Motele</option>
<option value="#">Panoramy</option>
<option value="#">Zamki</option>
<optgroup label="Sport i rekreacja">
<option value="#">Baseny</option>
<option value="#">Hala Sportowa</option>
<option value="#">Korty tenisowe</option>
<option value="#">Orliki</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
           <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 450px"></div> 
       
           <div id="pasekBoczny"></div> 
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Wybierz obiekt..."
});
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
enter code here
```